# Conexión VSTO (Visual Studio, para crear AddIn) a SAP

Tags: visual-studio, vba, macros, sap, abap

estoy migrando mis macros (VBA) a Visual Studio para hacer que sean addins, pero NO encuentro cual es la variante de esta parte del código.

```vb
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
```

Este código lo genera SAP para hacer conexiones, con VBA lo corre sin problemas, básicamente SAP te genera un archivo .VBScrip copias y pegas el código en algún modulo de VBA y listo, pero, esto no funciona en VSTO. jajajaja y por mas que estoy buscando no encuentro una variante.

Answer (score 1):

Para ti del futuro que tienes el mismo problema que yo.
La respuesta no estaba quitar los if IsObject y los let, ya que esos no son del lenguaje en Visual Basic, pero si para Visual Basic For Application. Asi que el codigo queda de la siguiente manera.

```
Public Sub Conexion_Sap()
        On Error GoTo error_de_coneccion
        SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        Connection = App.Children(0)
        SESSION = Connection.Children(0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        Exit Sub
error_de_coneccion:
        MsgBox("No hay sesion abierta en SAP")
    End Sub
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.